# java.io.IOException: error=12, Cannot allocate memory

Tags: java, swap

On one of the machines, my app throws exception

```
 Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=12, Cannot allocate memory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 7 more
```

Based on the error message it is doing a fork and getting OOM, which this article describes clearly and provides some fix. http://www.bryanmarty.com/2012/01/14/forking-jvm/
I have 32 GB ram on that box, and 16 GB on the other. On this host, I don't have swap, but on the 16 GB box, I have swap space.The process runs on 16 GB box, but not on this one. Now, the question is, do I really need swap space even when I have enough RAM? What else can be the cause of that problem?

Comment: Did you set the maximum heap space with `-Xmx`? Some related information here: https://plumbr.io/outofmemoryerror/java-heap-space

Comment: yes, I have doubled the memory and did not help.